# res\ and AndroidManifest.xml not added to my .apk file

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

Due to a change of computers, I had to do a new installation of Eclipse and the Android SDK. I copied over my work environment (directory) and voila, everything works fine when compiling and running my app in the emulator.

However, when creating a distribution package, the generated .apk file is just about +half the size of the previous versions+ and produces the +"There was a problem parsing the package"+ eror message when trying to install it on a phone.

On a closer check, I found that the following files are not added to the .apk file:

```
res/ folder
AndroidManifest.xml
resources.arsc
```

There are no error messages in the Error log in Eclipse and I have already disabled Proguard (just to sort it out as a possible cause). Any idea?

Comment: How did you import the project in the new installation?

Comment: At first I didn't import anything, I told Eclipse about the location of my work directory when asked, and it opened everything just fine. When I found out about these problems, after studying  the SO answers given so far ;-) I removed the .metadata directory and imported my project by "Import" - "Existing projects into workspace". That didn't change anything however.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try two things...

First, the obvious would be to open the project and then use Project -> Clean.

Second (if the above doesn't fix it), close the project then right-click on it in the Package Explorer and select Delete - this won't delete the project files (unless you select the checkbox which you obviously don't want to do). When the project is deleted go to File -> New -> Project. Select "Android Project From Existing Code" then select the project folder as the source.

Comment: Here I get the error message "Invalid project description.
  C:\www\e-Work\testing overlaps the location of another project: 'testing'"